# How to benchmark channel / mutex memory consumption / allocation?

Tags: go, profiling, benchmarking, pprof

I try to compare using channel for one value vs using mutex. Channel example:

```
func BenchmarkNewDummy(b *testing.B) {
    one := make(chan string, 1)
    two := make(chan string, 1)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(2)
    go doWork(&wg, one)
    go doWork(&wg, two)
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println(<-one)
    fmt.Println(<-two)
}

func doWork(wg *sync.WaitGroup, one chan string) {
    defer wg.Done()
    one <- "hell0"
}
```

command:

```
go test -bench=. -benchmem -run BenchmarkNewDummy -cpuprofile cpuCh.out -memprofile memCh.prof
```

output doesn't provide any useful info

```
goos: darwin
goarch: amd64
BenchmarkNewDummy-8     hell0
hell0
hell0
hell0
hell0
hell0
hell0
hell0
hell0
hell0
2000000000               0.00 ns/op            0 B/op          0 allocs/op
PASS
ok        0.508s
```

with mutex situation almost the same:

```
func BenchmarkNewDummy(b *testing.B) {
    one := ""
    two := ""
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(2)
    var mu sync.Mutex
    go func() {
        mu.Lock()
        defer mu.Unlock()
        defer wg.Done()
        one = "hello"
    }()
    go func() {
        mu.Lock()
        defer mu.Unlock()
        defer wg.Done()
        two = "hello"
    }()
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println(one)
    fmt.Println(two)
}
```

output:

```
goos: darwin
goarch: 
BenchmarkNewDummy-8     hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
2000000000               0.00 ns/op            0 B/op          0 allocs/op
PASS
ok        0.521s
```

memory graph looks almost the same but with mutext bigger memory allocation, but not informative as well:
[image][image]

Are the any to compare channel and mutex memory consumption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing the benchmarking wrong. Quoting from package doc of [`testing`](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Benchmarks):

> A sample benchmark function looks like this:
>
> ```
> func BenchmarkHello(b *testing.B) {
>     for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
>         fmt.Sprintf("hello")
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> **The benchmark function must run the target code b.N times.**  During benchmark execution, b.N is adjusted until the benchmark function lasts long enough to be timed reliably.

Also don't include `fmt.PrintXX()` calls in benchmarked code, you distort the results.

Benchmark these functions rather:

```
func newDummy() {
    one := make(chan string, 1)
    two := make(chan string, 1)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(2)
    go doWork(&wg, one)
    go doWork(&wg, two)
    wg.Wait()
    <-one
    <-two
}

func doWork(wg *sync.WaitGroup, one chan string) {
    defer wg.Done()
    one <- "hell0"
}

func newDummy2() {
    one, two := "", ""
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(2)
    var mu sync.Mutex
    go func() {
        mu.Lock()
        defer mu.Unlock()
        defer wg.Done()
        one = "hello"
    }()
    go func() {
        mu.Lock()
        defer mu.Unlock()
        defer wg.Done()
        two = "hello"
    }()
    wg.Wait()
    _, _ = one, two
}
```

Like this:

```
func BenchmarkNewDummy(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        newDummy()
    }
}

func BenchmarkNewDummy2(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        newDummy2()
    }
}
```

Benchmarking it with:

```
go test -bench . -benchmem
```

I get an output like this:

```
BenchmarkNewDummy-4    605662      1976 ns/op     240 B/op      5 allocs/op
BenchmarkNewDummy2-4   927031      1627 ns/op      56 B/op      4 allocs/op
```

From the results, `newDummy()` performs 5 allocations on average, totaling 250 bytes. `newDummy2()` performs 4 allocations, total of 56 bytes.

Comment: thanks a lot! now i see that mutex has advantage in memory allow 56 B/op vs 240 B/op. if i sort out it correct